# Rails 4: setting link destination in CoffeeScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am building a Rails 4 app and I am pretty new to JavaScript and CoffeeScript.

In `posts.coffee`, I have the following function:

```
jQuery ->
  console.log("test")
  $(".new-post").on "click", ->
    date = $(this).data("date")
    location.href = "/posts/new?post[date]=#{date}"
```

The goal of this function is to allow users to click in the `.new-post` div in a custom calendar view named `calendar-view` — `/calendars/:id/calendar_view` — and send them to `/calendars/:id/posts/new` while passing the `:date` attribute through the URL.

—————

**UPDATE**: my routes are:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
end
```

—————

**UPDATE 2**: here is what I have in `calendar_view.html.erb`:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "new-post", data: {date: date} do %>
```

—————

How can I implement the `/calendars/:id` par of the URL in my CoffeeScript function?

Comment: Can you also post you routes?

Comment: Sure. I just updated the question.

Comment: @ThibaudClement You are close. Keep your `id` in the `div` as a custom attribute using `data`.  Then inside the coffeescript fetch the `id` and make the url

Comment: @ThibaudClement is there a reason why you are using JS to do this, instead of a plain `anchor` tag?

Comment: @Vucko: yes, the reason is that the `calendar_view` view displays a calendar, and what I am trying to implement is to allow users to click in the cells of the calendar, get sent to the `posts new` view so they can create a post with the date of the post already saved, from the cell they clicked on.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: thanks a lot for your explanation. Any chance you could point me into the right direction to achieve what you recommend? I am not very comfortable with JS / CoffeeScript yet, and any help is highly appreciated ;)

Comment: @ThibaudClement I will, give me a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, you have a `<div>`. Now you can take the advantage of the `data` attribute to help you to construct the url.

```
<%= conent_tag :div, class: "new-post", data: {calendar_id: calendar.id, date: date } do %>
   # I assume you have the access to the object `calendar`, so use it.
   # some code.
<% end %>
```

Now inside the coffee-script code write like:

```
jQuery ->
  console.log("test")
  $(".new-post").on "click", ->
    date = $(@).data("date")
    calendar_id = $(@).data("calendar-id")
    location.href = "/calendars/#{calendar_id}/posts/new?post[date]=#{date}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arup Raskshit. I have updated the question with the content of my `calendar_view.html.erb` file. From what I understand in your answer, I should replace `<%= content_tag :div, class: "new-post", data: {date: date} do %>` with  `<%= content_tag :div, class: "new-post", data: {date: date, calendar_id: @calendar.id} do %>` and then add `calendar_id = $(@).data("calendar_id")` to `posts.coffee`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ThibaudClement Exactly like that.  I gave an example about the approach.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. I still get some UI issues (eg: I need to click several times in the cell for the onclick event to be listened to, but that's for another question). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works well, I will outline a few complementary approaches below:

Here is the most simple approach, a script tag can be generated in the template, which will be evaluated on the client.

In your controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    @registry = {
      calendar_id: @calendar.id
    }
  end
end
```

In view:

```
<script>
REGISTRY = <%= @registry.to_json.html_safe %>
</script>
```

You can later access the global registry from your coffeescript code. All you have to ensure is that the script tag that (directly or indirectly) references your coffeescript is included after the above script tag.

The advantage of doing this over the accepted solution is that it avoids unnecessary DOM access. It is an emergent best practice in javascript community to not read data from the DOM because DOM access is slower. Ideally DOM should be treated only as a rendering solution, and not a data store.

While on one hand the html for exposing the REGISTRY through a script tag can be refactored out to a shared partial, the actual decision of what variables to be made available to the client remains inside the controller, which is where IMHO it belongs. It helps to keep logic/decisions from leaking into your presentation layer.

Furthermore if you are reliant on DOM attributes you cannot use that data (eg. for initiating requests or preloading content) before the DOM is ready. This is usually not a major limitation though.

However, the above approach results in increasingly repetitive code if the app is large. It is much better if the url handling can be decoupled from the code that actually does the network communication.

A great library that makes this very easy is [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes). It creates javascript functions for routes defined in rails. So in your coffeescript code you could write:

```
path = Routes.new_post_path({ calendar_id, date })
```

just like you would in your erb partial.

If you are worried about protecting your private routes from being available to outside world through javascript or increasing amount of javascript bloat as more and more routes are added to a large application, js-routes has configuration options that allows you to expose only a subset of the routes.

This has a very powerful benefit - your routes.rb file is the single source of truth about your routes - just like it was meant to be. Tomorrow if you have to change your routes, you don't have to hunt through several coffeescript files where you have used string interpolated urls.